# How to implement zoom and move in my ng2-chart

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular6, ng2-charts

Suppose there are one chart and two buttons. The buttons do this:

1. active zoom
2. move chart

This is my hmtl code:

```
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
  <button (click)="zoom()">Zoom</button>
  <button (click)="move()">Move</button>
</div>
```

In my ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class ExampleChart implements OnInit {

   @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;

    ngOnInit() {
   }

public barChartOptions:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,

    zoom: {
        // Boolean to enable zooming
        enabled: false,
        sensitivity:0.5,
        // Enable drag-to-zoom behavior
        drag: true,

        // Zooming directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable 
        // Eg. 'y' would only allow zooming in the y direction
        mode: 'xy',
        rangeMin: {
            // Format of min zoom range depends on scale type
            x: null,
            y: null
        },
        rangeMax: {
            // Format of max zoom range depends on scale type
            x: null,
            y: null
        }
    }
  };

  public barChartLabels:string[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series D'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series '}

  ];

  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public zoom():void {
    this.barChartOptions.zoom.enabled=true;
    this.chart.ngOnChanges({});

  }
  public move():void{

  }
}
```

The zoom operation works fine, but there are some problem to resolve:

1. when I click on the button "zoom", I enabled the zoom but after "
   `this.chart.ngOnChanges({});`" reload the chart and in this way the
   zoom works, but I want that the chart is not load again. ngOnChanges is necessary?
2. I want that when the button move is cliked the chart stop zoom operation and start to move only to rigth or left, and if there was zoom in chart I don't want that is cancelled.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177302/how-to-zoom-charts-in-chart-js-using-angular-7